# Inject a service into a class in Angular: why is it an anti-pattern and which alternatives do I have?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access a Service from a Class in Angular. In all QAs I found on this site, everyone keeps saying that it's something that should not be done, but I'm failing to see what would be the alternative in my specific case.

This is an hypothetical scenario which is an oversimplification of my real one.

I have one resource User for whose I get data from the server. So I created one service which has the role to get the user from the server and pass it to the component.

```js
this.http.get(url, this.loginService.getEntryHttpOptions()).subscribe(
  data => {
    const response = new User(data.json());
    observer.next(response);
    observer.complete();
  }
)
```

'User' is a class defined like this:

```js
export class User {

  code: string = 'NEW';
  id: number = 0;
  hobbies: Array<Hobby>;

  constructor(input) {  
    this.code = String(input.code);
    this.id = Number(input.id);
    for let(hobby of input.hobbies) {
      this.hobbies.push( new Hobby(hobby) );
    }
  } 
}

export class Hobby {

  code: string = 'en';
  name: string = 'English';
  available_options = [];

  constructor(input) {   
    if (input) {
      input.code ? this.code = String(input.code) : false;
      input.name ? this.name = String(input.name) : false;
    }

    hobbyService.gethobbies().subscribe(
      hobbies => {
        this.available_options = hobbies
      }
    ) 
  }   
}
```

As you can see, I'd need to access one service from the hobby class. I think both user and hobby should be classes and not services because I have many of them and each of them should be different by all the others.

On the other hand, the hobbyService should be a singleton because it will do only one server call and then keep the values in memory until the app gets closed, and it is also called by many other services and components all around the app, so I made it a service.

I could separate the data and the actions (putting all the actions like hobbyService.gethobbies somewhere else and then assigning this value to my object), but I'd like to keep everything separated so that each object can do its own stuff.

As I said this is an hypothetical scenario but in my real use case I have to pass around 30 services around...

Anyhow, I can not access services from my class.

What I've tried until now:

- I could pass my services to the User constructor from the component, but this will mean that every time I have to use this I'll have to remember to pass the services, and also each class should forward the services to their children and so on. Which does not looks nice to me.
- I could do this once, and have my services always available... but I know it's not good (even if this works EXACTLY as I'd like it to work!):
  `document['services'] = { hobbiesService: this.hobbiesService };`

Do I have any other option? Something not as cumbersome as having to pass those things around?

Answer (score 3):

> I could separate the data and the actions (putting all the actions
>   like hobbyService.gethobbies somewhere else and then assigning this
>   value to my object) ...

Yes, you should separate your data retrieval logic from your data objects. It's common practice to separate data retrieval, data models and data presentation.

If you have multiple Services that each fetch different data I would suggest creating a higher level Service that's using those lower lever Services to fetch required data and combine it as needed.

It could look something like this:

**Lower Level Service 1**

```js
// UserService
interface UserData { code: string, id: number, hobbyIds: string[] }

getRawUserData(): Observable<UserData> {
  return this.http.get<UserData>(url, this.loginService.getEntryHttpOptions()).pipe(
    catchError( /* error handling */ )
  )
}
```

**Lower Level Service 2**

```js
// HobbyService
getHobby(hobbyId: string): Observable<Hobby> {
  return this.http.get<string[]>(`url/id=${hobbyId}`).pipe(
    map(data => ({ code: 'en', name: 'English', available_options: data } as Hobby)),
    catchError( /* error handling */ )
  );
}
```

**Higher Level Service**

Use a mapping operator like `switchMap` or combine multiple Observables using `forkJoin` to construct your desired return type from multiple lower level service calls.

```js
getUser(): Observable<User> {
  return this.userService.getRawUserData().pipe(
    switchMap(userData => 
      forkJoin(
        userData.hobbyIds.map(hobbyId => this.hobbyService.getHobby(hobbyId))
      ).pipe(map(hobbies => new User(userData, hobbies)))
    )
  );
}
```